# Cómo conectar el Data Modeler con SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero documentar una base de datos de `SQL Server 2008`. Me han pedido el Diagrama y las especificaciones de las tablas, campos, tipo de datos, etc (Diccionario de Datos).

El problema es que no encuentro un programa adecuado a mis requerimientos. El `Erwin Data Modeler` tiene una herramienta de ingeniería inversa, pero no me es útil debido a que no me permite especificarle solo las tablas que deseo diagramar, a lo mucho me pide los esquemas (Pero es en este programa que me piden hacer la diagramación). El `Management Studio` de `SQL Server` no es una opción por que es el mismo que administra las Bases de Datos (Implica modificar la BD de alguna manera) y tampoco es muy flexible con la elección de las tablas.

De modo que recurrí al `Data Modeler` trabaja perfecto con una base de datos de `Oracle`, se pueden hacer diagramas, generar scripts (este último me ayudó a pasar los diagramas al `Erwin`), y hasta generar documentación de objetos, etc. Pero no he podido conectarlo con el `SQL Server 2008` para hacer lo mismo que hice con `Oracle`. He descargado el `jtds-1.2.jar` para hacer la conexión pero no sé exactamente como hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen necesito un programa que me permita **elegir** las tablas a las cuales quiero diagramar (Son cosas que se logran con el `Data Modeler`) y luego poder abrirlas en el `Erwin`(Con el script que genera este último) que es el programa de destino. Y también la documentación de campos, aunque este sea un tema secundario a la pregunta.

Me sería útil si conocen de algún otro método, programa o procedimiento.

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionar el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Si es `SQL Server edición Express`, es probable que lo de la **conexión** se deba a que esta edición usa puertos dinámicos, como explico en este post en mi blog: [SQL Server 2012 edición Express y su puerto TCP/IP](https://mastergt68.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/sql-server-2012-edicin-express-y-su-puerto-tcpip/). Se que no es la versión que indicas, pero el concepto aplica.

> Modifica el puerto dinámico para que sea el 1433 y luego en JDBC URL escribes *jdbc:sqlserver:///SQLEXPRESS/Databases/:1433;user=sa;password;Driver Class:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver*, remplazando lo que está entre <> por los valores que tienes.

Para la otra parte de la pregunta, yo he usado [ApexSQL Doc](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_doc.aspx) y también [Visio](https://blogs.office.com/2017/02/23/visualize-work-in-powerful-new-ways/) para obtener el diagrama `Entidad/Relación`.

Estas herramientas son de pago. Se que hay otras como [SQL Doc de Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/) y las de Devart, específicamente [dbForge Documenter for SQL Server](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/documenter/) y `dbForge Studio for SQL Server` que tiene un [diagramdor de base de datos](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/database-diagram.html). De nuevo, éstas también son de pago. Tendrás que evaluar a ver cuál o cuáles te convienen más y decidir por su compra.